# What are different symbols in the Spiderman: Across the Spiderverse teaser?

Tags: spider-man-across-the-spiderverse

There have been many symbols shown in the teaser trailer of **Spiderman: Across the Spiderverse**.

Edit - Previously known as Spiderman: Into the Spiderverse 2

[image: logo of spiderman into the spiderverse 2]

What are these different symbols representing? What characters are represented by these symbols?

Are these characters present in the movie or is it just random marketing gimmick?

Comment: not sure I get it. If you are talking about this https://twitter.com/i/status/1190373194374377472 well... it's just a spider. I think it's too early to say what does it mean, it could be anything or nothing at all.

Comment: I am confused. Isn't the linked video answering the question?

Comment: @Taladris that video was added by PaulieD in edit

Comment: I mean, obviously it means the multiple characters in the multiverse...now, which characters, new rockstars channel analyzed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmheEqTf5gU

Comment: The stars on the US flag represent the *number* of member States, but none of them represents any *one* State.  Do these spiders need to represent anything other than the multiplicity of Spider-Men, collectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CBR.com](https://www.cbr.com/into-the-spider-verse-teaser-glitches-hints-at-key-spider-men/) has a post on this, but it seems to be mostly conjecture. They're saying that the white logo has something to do with [Mr. Negative](https://www.marvel.com/characters/mr-negative). The red and yellow logo is commonly thought to represent [Supaidaman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185116/), although it could also belong to [Jessica Drew](https://www.marvel.com/characters/spider-woman-jessica-drew). The black logo on the red background could belong to [Spider-Carnage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnage_(comics)#Spider-Carnage_(Ben_Reilly)), or alternatively it could belong to [Ben Reilly](https://www.marvel.com/characters/scarlet-spider-ben-reilly).

As Gustavo Gabriel pointed out in [comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105015/what-are-different-symbols-in-spiderman-into-the-spiderverse-2-teaser/105055#comment180053_105015), the New Rockstars YouTube channel also has a [video](https://youtu.be/MmheEqTf5gU) on this topic. According to them, the red and white on black logo belongs to Cindy Moon, aka [Silk](https://www.marvel.com/characters/silk-cindy-moon). Sony's Amy Pascal has [said](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/12/sony-spider-man-future-amy-pascal-phil-lord-interview) that Silk will be included in future films.

Edit: Phil Lord [confirmed](https://twitter.com/philiplord/status/1191546906884788229) Supaidaman.